# Select hash id from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an array with multiple hashes

```
[#<Campaign id: 144> , #<Campaign id: 146>]
```

I've stripped out the other fields for simplicities sake, but the object does have many fields.  What I want to end up with is an array of unique hash IDs, for example: `[144, 146]`.  Of course there are many ways to do this naively, but I want to know what the best way to do it is.  I'm struggling to find a function that was built for this purpose.

Comment: Confused, those look like objects, not hashes. Can't you just collect the id property from each array element using... collect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
your_array.map(&:id)
```

or

```
your_array.map{|i| i.id}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have there appears not to be an array of hashes, but rather an array of some other type of object (`Campaign`). You should be able to get this via the `object_id` property and `.map()`:

```
your_array.map(&:object_id)
```

Comment: presumably, if it's Rails, you'd actually use `array.map(&:id)` (shorthand of `array.map { |object| object.id }` )